# How can I check if street view is enabled?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I want to place a marker on a Google map, but only when street view is active. If the "normal" map is displayed, then the marker shouldn't be visible.

Does anyone know how to check if street view is active on a Google Map?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you looked at the [Streetview documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewService).  What does your code/map look like?

Answer (score 1):

Just read `map.getStreetView().getVisible();`

```
var svpIsVisible = map.getStreetView().getVisible();
 if (svpIsVisible){
   // visible -do something
 }
 else (
   //Not visible - do something else
 )
```

Comment: @AlexBaur, I'm not sure if it was what you needed or if you're being sarcastic, but if the answer helped you feel fee to up-vote it and/or accept it. :-)